# Please clean up your comments

Tags: discussion, comments

Please remove all of the comments on the question

[What is this old potential stone or relic found in a Kansas pasture?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13833/what-is-this-old-potential-stone-or-relic-found-in-a-kansas-pasture)

except for the last one, by gansub. It's the only one that should have been there in the first place.

**Update: It's been done. Many thanks!**

The OP was clueless about what he was doing, and later defensive about it. But that's **completely irrelevant**. Everyone should have seen the 1 under the user's name and offered guidance instead of confrontation.

Instead, several high-reputation users participated in a rather pointless argument about an abbreviation. At the same time, nobody bothered to fix the broken image embedding.

If I look at the [Earth Science beta evaluation on Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/earth-science), I see **3.3 questions per day - needs work**. Part of that work should be encouraging users to improve their answers, not engaging in fits of pique because a question wasn't asked in a way they liked.

It's hardly limited to Earth Science SE, of course. I recommended SE to a colleague once but she avoids it now, because of this very behavior. But we can be better.

I've participated in more of these online forums than I care to think about, and I realize that the treatment of brand new users is a discussion that was going on before SE existed and will go on long after we're all gone.  But we can at least clean up this particular mess.

Comment: I started the mess. My bad. Won't happen again.